# SSH Connection on Remmina using AWS public key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, remmina

I am trying to login to remmina using the ssh .pub key. but when I try to connect it is asking me to ssh private key passphrase.

[image]

I do not know what I am doing wrong but here is a debug log.

```
[SSH] ssh_config_parse_line: Unsupported option: SendEnv, line: 53
[SSH] ssh_config_parse_line: Unsupported option: HashKnownHosts, line: 54
[SSH] ssh_config_parse_line: Unsupported option: GSSAPIAuthentication, line: 55
[SSH] socket_callback_connected: Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[SSH] ssh_client_connection_callback: SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
[SSH] ssh_analyze_banner: Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
[SSH] ssh_analyze_banner: We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 7.2 (70200)
[SSH] ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
[SSH] ssh_agent_get_ident_count: Answer type: 12, expected answer: 12
[SSH] ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
[SSH] ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub: No such file or directory
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub: No such file or directory
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
[SSH] ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
[SSH] ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/identity.pub: No such file or directory
[SSH] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file: Error opening /home/Workstation/.ssh/identity: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me to connect to via ssh on remmina using public key?

Answer (score 0):

When you rolled your key you were given the option to protect those bits with a passphrase. A local password agent could unlock it for you, if you like.

You may want to re-roll your key and this time use the empty password with it. You would need to also tell the server about your new key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I regenerated the dsa (ssh-keygen -t dsa) without passphrase but it is still asking the passphrase if I provide nothing it is returning null.